# How to Find last IISreset time in C#

Tags: c#, sharepoint, iis

Hi i am working with sharepoint 2007 , and the requirement is to stop all workflows on sharepoint lists in progress after an IISreset.

**How do i Programatically find the last IISReset time using C#.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SCM or Service Control manager logs this.  You need to open up the system log in Event Viewer and look in there.

```
EventLog eventLog = new EventLog();

eventLog.Log = "System";

eventLog.Source = "Service Control Manager"; //Not 100% sure thats correct

eventLog.MachineName = "IIS Server name";

foreach (EventLogEntry log in eventLog.Entries)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}\n",log.<Property you need for info>);
}
```

I would say figure out what the event ID would be and key off that instead of just matching Error text or anything along those lines.  Just off a quick search I believe its 3203.  Below is a WMI solution as well I would suggest do some performance testing on Both.  There is another method that is EventLogReader which requires you to have windows vista or 7 or windows server 2008 or higher that you can use as well.

```
var query = new ObjectQuery("Select * from Win32_NTLogEvent
                         where LogFile='Application'");
var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query);
var result = searcher.Get(); // Result is your Collection of Event Log entries 
foreach(var eventEntry in result)
{
  //access properties in this fashion would suggest try parse 
  int id = int.Parse(eventEntry["Event ID Property Name"].ToString());
}
```

Comment: Hi , but i need to do it programatically using C# .

Comment: Hello Edited to access Event Log

Comment: Thanks , this is helpful , however would querying the eventlog be a time consuming process considering we have huge logs in the evenviewer ?

Comment: Potentially yes, if you have a huge number of system events going on it could be time consuming so I certainly would recommend if you are doing this to thread it in some form or fashion or if you are making this a web app to make it some type of ajax call with a loading gif to show its a log running process.

Comment: Would this result in the same performance constraint: EventLogEntry log = eventLog.Entries[0];
                EventLogEntry logtwo = eventLog.Entries[eventLog.Entries.Count - 1];

Comment: I am not sure about that if you are looking for Maximum performance from what I am reading WMI would be the best option.  If you would give just a moment I will see if I can get an Example for that

Comment: thanks that would be helpful , basically this code has to run inside a SharePoint timer job and i have to keep in mind that timerjob doesnt over run.